# Равномерное распределение n точек на площади произвольной формы

Tags: алгоритм

Какие существуют алгоритмы для реализации этого для 2D плоскости (сетка точек)? Удалось найти только для примитивных фигур алгоритмы. В какую сторону двигаться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для произвольной - метод скульптора - сгенерировать точки в охватывающем прямоугольнике, и отсечь лишние, за пределами фигуры.

Если это полигон - триангулировать его, посчитать площади треугольников, выбирать треугольник с вероятностью, пропорциональной площади, и генерировать точку в нём.

Comment: Второй способ более правильный в контексте условий задачи (причём необязательно это полигон). В первом же, N точек - это *определённое* количество, и если генерить с избытком, то после отсечения, придётся уже вычислять, какие точки удалять, а этот процесс практически аналогичен тому, как их расставить. Действие обратное, но алгоритм тот же.

Comment: Можно уточнить выражение "генерировать точку в треугольнике". Это значит, что нужно вычислять центр каждого треугольника и округлять до int (так как позиции нодов целочисленные), потом в центр расположить точку? Или точку нужно расположить на ноду какого-то ребра треугольника? Не очень понятно, как распределить равномерно точки по треугольникам.

Comment: @Ростислав Лизогубов Я воспринял задачу так, что нужно сделать **случайное** равномерное распределение точек. Если это не то, что вы имели в виду, то нужно уточнение условия.

Comment: У меня есть граф равномерных точек (сетка) различной формы. И нужно по этим точкам разделить n точек, но не добавляя новых между существующими, а как бы пометить. То есть, распределённая точка должна быть точкой из изначального графа.